# If Alice tries to shift into Bob the same night that Bob is also killed by the militia, what happens?

Tags: werewolv.es

Is Alice still able to successfully shift and assume Bob's identity if Bob was killed by the militia the same night?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this instance Alice will appear to die, and Bob will appear to survive the shot.

Kills are resolved against the player not the identity.

So assume:

- PlayerA has identity Alice (Shifter)
- PlayerB has identity Bob (Normal Player)
- PlayerM has identity Mike (Militia)

Then:

- PlayerA chooses to shift, and targets Bob (PlayerB)
- PlayerM chooses to kill, and targets Bob (PlayerB)

In the morning:

- PlayerB is killed (From wolf kill and militia shot).
- PlayerA and PlayerB swap identities (Shift)

So the identities are now:

- PlayerA has identity Bob (Shifter)
- PlayerB has identity Alice (Normal Player)
- PlayerM has identity Mike (Militia)

The game will then show:

- Alice (PlayerB) died in the night